# Setting styles on different faces of a GWT CustomButton using UiBinder

Tags: gwt, styling, uibinder

I'm trying to set style names on different faces of ToggleButton (i.e. upFace, downFace, ...). It looks like setting styleName on a face doesn't work. For example the following won't work:

```
<g:ToggleButton>
    <g:upFace styleName='{style.myToggleButton-up}' />
</g:ToggleButton>
```

But I noticed when setting the style name on ToggleButton itself...

```
<g:ToggleButton styleName='{style.myToggleButton}' />
```

... the generated HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="GPAKHSCBGG GPAKHSCBGG-up" role="button" aria-pressed="false">...</div>
```

However, even if I have {style.myToggleButton-up} defined, it is not populated to GPAKHSCBGG-up. So I'm wondering how can I do this without having to mock the global .gwt-ToggleButton-up stylesheet. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> Add @external myToggleButton, myToggleButton-up; to ui:binder file.

Answer (score 1):

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~ToggleButton

All GWT components have predefined CSS Class definitions, what you tried didn't override the definitions.

Comment: Well, it works only when defining the stylesheets in the global .css file (either by setting styleName or stylePrimaryName). But it doesn't seem to work when defining the styles in <ui:style> of .ui.xml file. I haven't found a solution for this yet and to me it looks like a GWT bug or feature lack.